# Analogue Visual Studio sln-files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea

I have some java projects, which are developed in IntelliJ IDEA. I want to rapidly open IDE with the needed project. However, I have to open IDEA and choose a project from it. Is there "sln-file" in IntelliJ IDEA?